# Is there a simple way mathematically to convert $X$ and $Y$ into $1$ where $X=Y$, and $0$ where $X \neq Y$

Tags: notation, computational-algebra

Given two integers, $X$ and $Y$, is there a simple mathematical expression that can be performed on them that resolves to $1$ when $X=Y$ and to $0$ when $X \neq Y$?

Something that can be expressed computationally without a conditional.  Additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, etc in a computational expression that will resolve to $1$ if $X=Y$ and $0$ if $X \neq Y$.  Essentially a test for equality that can be used in a computational expression without using an actual conditional statement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)?

Comment: [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), $\delta_{XY}$, is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes: $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}1&x=y\\0&x\ne y\end{cases}$

Comment: I've updated the question.  But if that's still not clear, then the question could be expressed this way:  What is a math trick that you can use where a person can choose two numbers, where you then give that person some calculations to do on them, which will always end up with 1 if those numbers were the same and zero if they weren't.